# error with angular provider

Tags: angular, angular-promise, angular-providers

```
I have a behaviour that I am not understanding when using with promises with angular.
When I use  the same code as follows, I got my data correctly

@Injectable()
export class Request {

    constructor(public http: Http)
    {

    }

    get(url): Promise<any>
    {
        return this.http.get("https://api.github.com/repos/php/php-src").map(response => {
            console.log(response.json());
            return response.json() || {success: false, message: "No response from server"};
        }).toPromise();
    }
```

However, when I change the data source to

```
http://mp3destadel.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/all.json
```

I get this error

```
Failed to load http://mp3destadel.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/all.json: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Could you help me to solve this problem please

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an angular problem. Check out CORS configuration of your s3 bucket.

[CORS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html)